# Logic app isn't reading Dynamics 365 Organization name from parameters

Tags: json, azure, microsoft-dynamics, azure-logic-apps, dynamics-365

I am deploying Azure Apps from Visual Studio and Azure app has connection to Dynamics 365. In Logic App Json template file, I am trying to set Dynamics 365 organization name in Azure App by passing a parameter while deployment. But it is unable to read the value of parameter and showing error in designer view as below. Below is what I have tried so far.

Parameter declared in Logic App Template File.

```
 "dynamics_organization_Name": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "orgxxxxxx.crm11"
}
```

Value is set in Parameters Json file.

```
"dynamics_organization_Name": {
  "value": "orgxxxxxx.crm11"
}
```

With in Logic App template Json, path has been changed to use value from parameter as below:

```
"path": "/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(parameters('dynamics_organization_Name')))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('contacts'))}/items/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(items('For_each_2')?['contactid']))}"
```

But when I deploy the service from Visual Studio, it deploys successfully but in Azure portal designer view it showing following error message as it is unable to get the value from parameter. Can anyone please suggest me how we can pass Dynamics 365 organization name from parameters?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add $ to the parameter name so it will be $dynamics_organization_Name

Hope this will fix the issue.